# how to check AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.refreshToken.tokenString is valid or not

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aws-sdk

```
 AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(
        requireContext(),
        object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
            override fun onResult(userStateDetails: UserStateDetails) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    if (userStateDetails.userState == UserState.SIGNED_IN) {
                       var awsSavedToken = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.idToken.tokenString
                        if (awsSavedToken == userStateDetails.details["token"].toString()){
                            toDashboard()
                        }
                    } 
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            }
        override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    Timber.tag("INIT").e(e, "Initialization error")
                    StateMachine.setLoading(false)
                    binding.llButton.gone = false
                }
            }
        })
```

> **AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.refreshToken.tokenString
> How to check its valid or not because in UserStateDetails.details get the "token" key but this is not refresh token it is "idToken"**

Comment: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android#initialize-amplify-auth I think you should use amplify and generating a token on main intent would be sufficient.

Comment: Ok Thanks @özkanpakdil